# Opening a file *with partially unknown filename* in executable directory

Tags: linux, directory, filenames, acl, access-control

I have a directory in linux which I can eXecute. Thus, I should be allowed to cd into the directory and open the file(s). I know that the file I am interested in starts with f and has a number attached to it.

e.g.: f987494748946578

Which command allows me to open any of the files starting with an fRANDOMNUMBER if I do not know the complete file name?

Comment: Did you mean to say that the directory does not have read permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none, by design.

You could try a `for` loop to check for the existence of all such files, since you know it to be digits only and you know how long the name is.  But you would have to brute force it.

The proper way would be to change the permissions on the directory to get read permissions, or ask your sysadmin to do this for you.

See also:

- [why can I see the directory without "read" privilege?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251276/135943)
- [Can a user brute-force a directory listing without having read permission on the directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62451/135943)

To answer the follow-up in the comments:

> The thing is it does not really matter which file is opened because all files are the same (content wise) and they all start with an f. As long as any file starting with f is opened its good. is there any command which allows to leave part of the file name blank (*) ?

There are many such commands and features (probably "file globs" is what you're thinking of), and *all* of them depend on the ability to list the contents of that directory, which requires read permissions.

So, no, there is no way besides:

1. Getting the directory permissions changed (which requires either root permissions, or that you be the owner of that directory);
2. Finding out the name from somebody else who knows it (e.g. send an email to Pete's sysadmin); or
3. Using brute force (i.e. just guessing names until you get one right).

Comment: The thing is it does not really matter which file is opened because all files are the same (content wise) and they all start with an f. 
As long as any file starting with f is opened its good. 
is there any command which allows to leave part of the file name blank (*) ?

Comment: @PeterParker, see edit I made to answer that.

Comment: Or having capability CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE, root has this capability on most systems.

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PeterParker please click the “accept” check mark to the left of my answer if it solved your question.  :)  That’s how we do “thank you” on this site.

Comment: @Wildcard Sorry, I did not know that. Should be done now.