# How can "which" find commands inside directories where I have no read permissions?

Tags: permissions, directory, path, which

On my work PC, I noticed that the which command seems to be able to find executables in directories, that I have no read permissions for.

```
$ export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH

$ ls /usr/sbin
ls: cannot open directory '/usr/sbin': Permission denied

$ which logrotate
/usr/sbin/logrotate
```

How does this work? Naively I would have implemented which by checking if `logrotate` is one of the files listed for any of the directories in the `$PATH` variable, which would fail.

Answer (score 2):

It works, because the which command only needs to check, if `/usr/sbin/logrotate` exists and whether the user has execute permissions on it.

While lacking read permissions (`chmod -r /usr/sbin`) on `/usr/sbin` prevents listing the directory, and thus prevents tab-completion or wildcard expansion, checking for the existence of a specific name requires only the execute bit (`chmod +x /usr/sbin`) which allows accessing file metadata, given a known name.

Disabling the execute permissions of the directory on the other hand, will result in the command becoming unfindable for `which` and unexecutable, despite the user having execute permissions on the file. We just can't access it anymore.

```
$ sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/
$ which logrotate # finds nothing
$ logrotate

Command 'logrotate' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install logrotate
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62476/120312 for more discussion.